# Facebox and rails not working!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebox

Am trying to use Facebox with rails, it's not working at all.

I have added all files to there right places:

- Install FaceboxRender gem install FaceboxRender
- Download jQuery
- Download facebox at https://github.com/defunkt/facebox
- Copy facebox js file to /public/javascripts/
- Copy facebox css file to /public/styleshees/
- Copy facebox all image files to /public/facebox/
- Update your layout’s `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` to add these js, css files

I have included FaceboxRender in my application controller

what am I missing here

this is a link am using just to test things:

```
<%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', posts_path %>
```

error:

```
can't convert Symbol into String
Extracted source (around line #1):

1:  <li><%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', posts_path %></li>
2: 
3: 
4: <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
```

I've tried adding `config.gem "facebox-render"` to my config/environment.rb 
but i just get errors!

Although I have installed the gem already,
I ran rake gems:install I get no problems as it's installed, but when I

rake db:migrate

I get this error:

```
Missing these required gems:
  facebox-render  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /opt/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.6 at /Users/Mister/.gem/ruby/1.8, /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Any help will be great!

Thanks

Dan

Comment: And those errors would be...?

Comment: What is the result of `gem env`?

Answer (score 1):

1.include `gem 'facebox-rails'` in the Gemfile

2.run `bundle install`

3.paste to your application.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox() 
})
```

4. in your `view` like something.html.haml ( if you use erb just add <% %>) just add

```
= link_to "Link name",your link, rel: "facebox"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line: 1:

<%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', posts_path %>

Change posts_path to the old style:

<%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', :url => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'} %>